# How to use set() during iteration?

Tags: python

How to use `set()` during iteration? I still have single value.

```
data = {'mynumber': set()}

example = Example.objects.filter(user=request.user)
for e in example:
    data['mynumber'].add(e.mynumber)
    print data #{'mynumber': set([15.0])}
```

Comment: Please provide complete code and more details.

Comment: What's `example`? Is it possible that all elements of `example` have the same `mynumber`?

Comment: Running that code with `xrange(100)` provides a set of numbers from 0 to 99.

Comment: With this filter, the code should work. If if doesn’t then you’re doing something wrong. Try printing `e.mynumber` instead of `data` to see what numbers occur in your data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Based on original edit**

You're adding to a set `mynumber`, which can contain only unique values, the results from a django query `Example.objects.filter(mynumber=5)` which only ever includes items where `mynumber` is 5... Ergo, you'll only ever end up with an empty set (no query results), or a set containing 5 (1 or more results).

---

**Note**

After you've traced through your code to check you're getting the values you're expecting, then you can get rid of the loop and just write your code as:

```
data = {'mynumber': set(Example.objects.filter(user=request.user).values_list('mynumber'))
```

Comment: `data` value is: `{"mynumber": [15.0]}` should be `{"mynumber": [15.0, 48.0]}` because this queryset return two objects.

Comment: @user3398153 Your example isn't correct then. Your example asks for objects where `mynumber=5`... This clearly isn't the case if you've got `15.0` in there and are expecting `48.0`... So what is the actual query ?

Comment: It does not matter how queryset is. It is `Example.objects.filter(user=request.user)`. This queryset return two objects. First object has value `mynumber = 15.0` and second object has value `mynumber = 48.0`. I except `data` with value `{"mynumber": [15.0, 48.0]}`

Comment: @user3398153 it definitely does matter how the queryset is. In your original post, you were attempting to add to a set the results from a queryset which only returned identical values and the problem you described was that you didn't understand why you only ended up with one item in the set. This answer addresses that. Since then you've modified the query to something that seems more reasonable, so now you should follow poke's advice and print mynumber to see what it is returning.

Comment: @user3398153 but the representation of the object itself isn't necessarily based on `mynumber`.... It's possible for all those Example objects to have different primary keys but the same `mynumber` value...

Answer (score 1):

try using `setdefault`:

When your condition satisfy, the following snippet will create an empty set for that number or key, so it will create if its not already exist else it will re-use:

```
data.setdefault('mynumber', set())
```

Comment: The key is static and already set to an empty set. `.setdefault()` won't change this behaviour at all.